# Error: CSRF token missing, hackathon-starter plus AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, csrf-protection

I'm integrating AngularJS into hackathon-starter. It was done as I mentioned it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121182/include-angular-into-hackathon-starter/29718416#29718416) with the following test.html and test.controller.js

```
<div>
    The record: {{record}}
</div>

<div align="right">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="createRecord()" onclick="window.location.href='/order/shipping'">
        <i class=""> Create record</i>
    </button>
</div>
```

test.controller.js

```
(function () {

'use strict';
var injectParams = ['$scope', '$location', '$http'];

function TestController($scope, $location, $http) {

    $scope.record = {
        interId: 1,
        sku: '107k',
        category: 'Useful'
    };

    function createRecord(record) {
        return $http.post('/order/create', record).then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        })
    }

    $scope.createRecord = function () {

        var record = $scope.record;

        createRecord(record)
            .then(function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    return $location.url('/shipping');
                }
                alert('Something wrong...');
            });
    }
};

TestController.$inject = injectParams;

angular.module('miniApp')
    .controller('TestController', TestController);
}());
```

It works if the value for csrf is set to false, like:

```
 app.use(lusca({
    csrf: false,
    xframe: 'SAMEORIGIN',
    xssProtection: true }));
```

When the value for csrf is set to true, than there is the error: 
**Error: CSRF token missing**

One of the options to solve this problem is to put request for '/order/create' path before the lusca configuration, like:

```
app.post('/order/create', passportConf.isAuthenticated, orderController.postCreateOrder);
app.use(lusca({
csrf: true,
```

...

But this solution is not quite elegant.

Another option would be to [whitelist dynamic URLs using regular expression](https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter#faq) inside the CSRF middleware. I tried this approach but I lack of experience how to do it properly. **How to solve this problem with whitelisting (concrete example)?**

I could be wrong, but it should be possible to pass the csrf within test.controller.js. How to do it I don't know. So, it would be nice if somebody would provide concrete example.

A solution with the whitelisting would be excepted because I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what I can tell `lusca` doesn't have any easily configurable CSRF whitelisting built in, and neither does the `hackathon-starter`. From the way your [linked article](https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter#faq) is phrased it sounds like they want you to do the whitelisting yourself in your own custom middleware. To do this, I think you might need to abandon your `app.use(lusca({}))` call and instead `app.use()` each lusca middleware individually, like so:

```
var csrfMiddleware = lusca.csrf();
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // Paths that start with /foo don't need CSRF
    if (/^\/foo/.test(req.originalUrl)) {
        next();
    } else {
        csrfMiddleware(req, res, next);
    }
});

app.use(lusca.csp({ /* ... */}));
app.use(lusca.xframe('SAMEORIGIN'));
app.use(lusca.p3p('ABCDEF'));
app.use(lusca.hsts({ maxAge: 31536000 }));
app.use(lusca.xssProtection(true));
```